# Win 7 Network Configuration Issues

Tags: windows-7, router, adsl

I have US ROBOTICS ADS L 4 PORT router and I use it to connect to the internet using my desktop.

I bought a new Toshiba laptop. So I connected it to router using the same wire disconnecting the desktop. But the problem is I cant go to internet. But the network solution center shows that I'm having internet. Also, When I ping the router sometimes it has success of 100% and some times 75% or 25%. I connected my laptop directly to desktop using the same wire and then there is no problem. And my desktop also having no problem to connect to internet using same wire and same router. I can go to internet from laptop using my dongle. I think I'm having some settings error relating to win 7. So please can anybody help me.

Comment: +1 for US robotics - that's a name I haven't heard in ages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try manually setting your ethernet wire-line configuration, versus the typical default of "Auto-Negotiation" - possibly 100 mbps at full duplex. This can be accomplished within the properties of the ethernet controller on your Toshiba.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it. Iam poor at this knowledge so can you please explain. That will be very much gratefull. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: Control Panel - Network and Internet - Network and Sharing Center - Change adapter settings, then "double click" on the ethernet adapter (typically labeled "Local Area Connection") - Properties - Configure - Advanced. At this point it will vary depending on the specific ethernet controller driver, but typically labeled "Link Speed & Duplex" which contains a "drop down" of different supported line-speed and duplex combinations.

Comment: I changed but not worked. Still having the problem. Internet also connecting but nothing dispalyed very much slow connection. And i cant connect to router using 192.168.1.1 it says bad connection. Shall i do a system restore. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you tried the different line-speed and duplex combinations?

Comment: At last it works. 10Mb/s Full Duplex. Thank you very much sir. If it is not bothering you can you please tell me what happens to my laptop? Is this a serious error? And thanks again for helping.

Comment: Nothing serious. You might try a different ethernet cable to see if you can match up a better speed combination.

Comment: But this cable works perfectly with my desktop on 100Mb/s Full duplex.

Comment: Different ethernet controller combination may have different tolerance variations. Sometime just enough to make things not work or work in some cases.